# Aggregating tabular data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of data which is date based in nature but with irregular reporting intervals. What I was hoping to do is to have my PHP backend send the data to the frontend JS/jQuery to display but in order to report effectively I need to be able to report by "week", "month", etc. I could try and do the SQL on the backend and structure different data series for each interval but that would be CPU intensive on the backend and I'd like the frontend to be a bit dynamic in being able to move between these intervals (aka, "show me monthly, no wait, show me weekly", etc.)

What I'm looking for -- I think -- is a JS/jQuery library that will help me take tabular data and group/aggregate it based on date based conditions. If need be I could try adding a column to the tabular structure which specifies the week number (and thereby simplifies the data math on frontend). In any case, I'm flexible at the moment and just hoping to hear of some good resources or approaches that have been tried before to solve this kind of problem.

**Note:** I am using [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) for tabular views on the frontend and [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) for graphical presentation. This is potentially not important but it might also open some creative alternatives.